# for loop within a false If (Python)

Tags: python

Why is the following code go into the for loop on line 6 when i = 3? I was thinking of if the If on line 4 is false, it shouldn't go into the for loop.

```
b = ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'is', 'lorem', 'dummy', 'impsum', 'is', 'the', 'printing', 'and', 'Industry', 'typesetting', 'industry.', 'Lorem', 'has', 'been']
count = 0
c = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i].lower() not in c:
        for j in range(len(b)):
            if b[i].lower() == b[j].lower():
                count += 1
        c.append(b[i].lower())
        print b[i], count
        count = 0    
print c
```

Comment: It _doesn't_ enter the loop on line 6 when i = 3. What makes you think it does?

Comment: As a tangent, you could use `from collections import Counter; Counter(c.lower() for c in b)`

Comment: @Rawing if you run it, you will see that it goes into the for loop.

Comment: Thanks guys. It was related to my indentation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. I get the following output when I run your code.

```
Lorem 3
Ipsum 1
is 2
dummy 1
impsum 1
the 1
printing 1
and 1
Industry 1
typesetting 1
industry. 1
has 1
been 1
['lorem', 'ipsum', 'is', 'dummy', 'impsum', 'the', 'printing', 'and', 'industry', 'typesetting', 'industry.', 'has', 'been']
```

You can see that it skipped printing `"lorem"` when `i` is 3.

Try printing `i` on the line `print b[i], count` if you're not convinced.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I didn't indent my code correctly on the console.